# "NOT IN" sql command in dplyr using result from a different query

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, dbplyr

I've been using dplyr with dbplyr to generate queries for my sql server and pull the data, but I couldn't find a way to execute the `NOT IN` sql command.

I'm trying to generate something like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID NOT IN id_list
```

where id_list is obtained from another query in dplyr

```r
id_list <- mutate(uid = distinct(id)) %>% select(uid) %>% collect()
```

`id_list` is a tbl_Microsoft SQL Server object.

What is the dplyr code to generate the SQL query?

Comment: negate `%in%` ? `EMPLOYEE[!EMPLOYEE$ID %in% id_list]` Or with `dplyr`, `EMPLOYEE %>%
  filter(!ID %in% id_list)`

Comment: thanks. the negate `%in%` didn't work. But i think the filter function would do the job. edit: the !ID threw an sql error

Comment: `as.data.frame(id_list)$uid` did the trick

Comment: Please see an answer I posted that addresses how to negate this query using dbplyr. Ronak Shah's answer was on the right track just needed to put the comparison in parentheses before negating.

Answer (score 2):

Ronak Shah's code is the correct idea, but is not negating properly. Right now it is just negating the ID instead of negating the results of the comparison.

```
EMPLOYEE %>% 
filter(!(ID %in% id_list)) %>%
collect()
```

If you put the comparison in parentheses and then negate the results of the comparison your query will work nicely (I tested it on a DB connection I have).

Comment: thanks. The main problem I had was that the `id_list` was a tibble and I had to convert it into a vector as I mentioned in the comment. I then used the vector with your snippet above.